# Sharepoint 2007 Document Library - lost ability to rename documents

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I administer a Sharepoint 2007 site.  All the following occur for any user, including the farm admin user, so I am assuming this has nothing to do with permissions.

On one document library only, the Name field is missing from the Edit Properties page for each document.  Folders are fine.  This means that users with permissions to edit or delete from the site are unable to rename documents.

If I navigate to the document library via the UNC path, I can use the Windows UI to rename documents without any problem.

The Name field is implicit in Document Libraries - you can't add or remove it as a column either via Content Type or the Document Library columns.

Any ideas what I can do to allow users of this doc library to be able to rename documents?

**Update**: This document library is *not* using a custom editform.aspx page.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible somebody created a custom edit form, and then made it the default edit form for the list? I believe that if you create a new edit form in SP Designer, it doesn't include the name field by default.

I would open the list with Designer, and see what the the default edit document is set to, and if there is another possible edit document that contains the Name field.

Also - I don't think it is actually possible to remove the Name field from a DocLib - but you could try using something like [SharePoint Manager 2007](http://spm.codeplex.com/) to analyze the list and see if the Name field is still actually attached to it.

Comment: Name field is definitely still attached to the list - if I switch to Datasheet view then I can see it, and if I add one of the other Name field options to the view (Name, linked to document for example), I can edit it.

Comment: In Sharepoint Designer I can see that EditForm.aspx is the default edit document.  When I open this up, it looks the same as EditForm.aspx in document libraries that don't have the problem - It shows [ Preview of List Form Web Part] and shows three columns that are replaced with the actual columns used in the document library when the page is delivered to the browser.

Comment: It isn't likely that someone created a custom edit form - unless I am very much mistaken, there isn't anyone else here who would know how, even if they wanted to do it.

Comment: @dunxd: yup, that sounds like a default edit form. If it had been customized, it would actually list the individual fields on the form instead.

Comment: I can confirm this - comparing the EditForm.aspx for this Document Library and that of a newly created Document Library - they appear to be identical.